# Consuming a WCF service in Windows Phone 8: Async methods?

Tags: .net, wcf, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013

For a while, my team has been using a WCF service (self-hosted on wsHTTP binding), and an ASP website that communicates with it. All methods in the WCF service are called synchronously and without error from the website.

However, with the addition of a Windows Phone 8 application, a complication has been introduced: WCF methods cannot be called synchronously, they must be called asynchronously.The synchronous version of the methods are not available in WP8, even when no asynchronous method has been defined in WCF.

This introduces the challenge of consuming this wcf service without actually modifying the code of the service. Is this possible? If not, how would the WCF implementation be modified to support asynchronous method calls? And are there resources available that can help with this specific issue? I've been searching all afternoon but this seems like a very specific issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Only the client call is async, the server operation call is still sync...

Comment: Ok, so when i do something like server.getDataAsync(), you're saying I'm going to need something in my client to handle that operation finishing? Could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the client call/code is asynchronous, the server operation call is still synchronous...

Client code:

```
var svc = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
svc.GetDataCompleted += (s, a) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(a.Result);
};
svc.GetDataAsync(42);
```

Server code:

```
[OperationContract]
public string GetData(int value)
{
    return "hello world: " + value; 
}
```

Maybe this article helps you:

- http://blog.rsuter.com/?p=281

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately my project is in VB.net (i know.) So im a bit unfamiliar with the syntax of your client code. In particular could you explain what this is doing?:

    svc.GetDataCompleted += (s, a) =>

When i try to do something similar in VB, i get the message that "GetDataCompleted is an event and cannot be called directly, use RaiseEvent to call an event"

Comment: After adding a WCF service as service reference, you can create a service client and call the async method. When the call has finished, the corresponding event is triggered with the result of the call...